# Two definitions of regular point of a smooth map

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I came across two different definitions of regular point of a smooth map.

Let $X$,$Y$ be two smooth manifolds and let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a smooth map. Write
$$
\mbox{rank} \; df = \max\{ \mbox{rank}\; d f(x): x \in X \}.
$$

Definition 1: We say $x \in X$ is a regular point if $\mbox{rank}\; d f(x) = \mbox{rank}\; df$. Otherwise it is a critical point.

Definition 2: We say $x \in X$ is a regular point if the differential $ df(x): T_xX \rightarrow T_{f(x)} Y$ at $x$ is surjective. Otherwise it is a critical point.

Now suppose $Y$ is simply $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $x$ is a critical point using definition 2. Then I can simply add one more dimension to $Y$. Define $f_1:= [f;f_0]$ where $f_0(x) = 0 \; \forall x \in X$. So $f_1$ is a smooth map from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Now $x$ is a regular point by Definition 1 but a critical point by Definition 2 since the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is just $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. So I am confused...

My guess is that there must be a way to reduce $Y$ to a "minimal dimension" so this scenario doesn't happen?

Comment: As your example shows, these two notions of regular point are different.  For what it's worth, I would have said the second one.

Comment: Why the second definition is worth? The same $x$ suddenly becomes a critical point if I add one more dimension to $Y$.

Comment: Where did you find definition 1? In 50 years I’ve never seen it. Why do we care about definition 2? Look up Sard’s Theorem, for example.

Comment: I saw this definition in a research seminar. But maybe this definition is rarely used.

Comment: I suggest you ask the seminar speaker where did they find this definition: It is utterly nonstandard.

Comment: I guess that if we take a regular value in the sense of definition 1, the rank theorem will still show that its preimage is a submanifold. That's the only thing I've been able to think of to support definition 1.

Comment: I think if we use definition 1, the Sard theorem still holds though. In fact,  the critical value has measure zero in the image of $f$ which may not be true if we are using definition 2.

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{rank} df$ is the maximal rank of all $df(x)$. I am not sure what its purpose should be. Obviously we have $\operatorname{rank} df \le \min (\dim X, \dim Y)$, but there is no reason why $\operatorname{rank} df = \dim Y$. Actually this is *impossible* if $\dim X < \dim Y$. But even if  $\dim X \ge \dim Y$ we may have  $\operatorname{rank} df < \dim Y$;  $\operatorname{rank} df$ may take may take any value between $0$ and $\dim Y$.

Thus definition 1. does not seem to produce something useful since any smooth map would by definition have regular points. You should ask the person who gave the definition what has been his intention.

Anyway, each regular point in the sense of 2. is one in the sense of 1. (because in that case $\operatorname{rank} df = \dim Y$). The converse fails  unless $\operatorname{rank} df = \dim Y$ (and this is in general not true).

Comment: I think one reason could be you can use definition 1 to say the critical values has measure zero in the image of $f$ instead of $Y$.